# Flutter Firebase Phone Auth .apk Missing valid app identifier, neither SafetyNet nor reCAPTCHA checks succeed

Tags: flutter, firebase, recaptcha, safetynet

currently using Firebase Phone Number Auth, worked well in debug mode in pc, including iPhone and android emulator.

when I "`flutter build apk`" and put it into my smartphone, the apps prompt
"Missing valid app identifier,

[image]

what I had done:

1. I had insert SHA-1 SHA-256 in firebase project setting
2. both the SHA is from android studio "`Gradle signingReport`" commands
3. I noticed all the SHA generated by android studio are same, including "`debug`", "`release`" etc.
4. I had enable google cloud console 's `Google Play Integrity API`, but didn't include any parameter or credentials, as in, just enabled, didn't do any configuration.
5. I had make sure the flutter app had the latest `google-service.json`
6. under build.gradle, I had following:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0-beta05'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
```

7. from `flutter build apk` commands, all the version are encountering same error.

I had go through every possible solution online, still not working.

How to make the Phone Auth works again?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490555/this-request-is-missing-a-valid-app-identifier-meaning-that-neither-safetynet-c

Comment: @RidhaRezzag helo, thanks for commenting! yep, I had tried that, but nothing worked

Comment: Have you solve the problem? I've the same problem but any solution seems not work