# Why can't I success in Firebase Phone Auth in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Recently I've built an android app based on Firebase Phone Authentication.
After publishing to Google Play, it caused error like below.
"This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither safetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded"
When I didn't restrict app singing in google developer console, it works fine.

There are many questions and answers about this problem on stack overflow and I tried all cases.
eg. [This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither safetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490555/this-request-is-missing-a-valid-app-identifier-meaning-that-neither-safetynet-c)
But it's still causing the same issue.
I found out safetyNet is deprecated, instead using google play integrity since last month.
But I couldn't find any example code for phone auth using google play integrity.
Does anybody resolve this already?

Comment: Did you add the release SHA1 Key in the firebase console ?

Comment: Of course, I added the release SHA1key in the firebase console.
I also added Google Publishing app signing SHA1key in Google Developer console.
But still not working.

Comment: We have recently released [Firebase Auth 21.2.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#auth_v21-2-0) which adds support for Play Integrity in phone auth. Can you test it with that version?

Comment: I tried with the latest Firebase Auth version 21.2.0.
This time, I got the below issue:
"this app is not authorized to use firebase authentication. please verify that the correct package name and sha-1 are configured in the firebase console"
I already verified the exact package name and sha-1 key in the firebase console.
Why is that?