# FlutterFlow: Firebase phone auth, OTP request gives error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, flutterflow

OTP is not being received on the non testing numbers.
I have added some test numbers for OTP and it works perfectly but when I request OTP with some other number it gives error
"*this request is missing a valid app identifier meaning that neither safetynet checks nor recaptcha...*"

The application is not published on play store yet
SHA-1 and SHA-256 are added
API & Services are added
Google Play Integrity is enabled

To my knowledge this feature does not work until the application is published and live. Am I right?
Is this a valid behavior of this auth feature?

Let me know if anymore information is required.

I have looked up the suggestions in the link [This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither safetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490555/this-request-is-missing-a-valid-app-identifier-meaning-that-neither-safetynet-c)