# Android: Firebase Mobile Number Verification: reCAPTCHA issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-console

I have integrated mobile number verification in Android Application. Application is live now. But I am facing this problem in new mobile numbers.

[image]

Mobile number verification is working fine in testing numbers even after the app live. I have deleted testing mobile numbers from Firebase Console but still, I am receiving OTPs in those numbers. The problem is that the OTP is not coming in other numbers (**numbers that are not registered ever before or not added in testing numbers**).

Few Notes:

1. I have already added SHA1 and sha256 keys **FROM** play console -> App ->  Release section  -> Setup -> App Integrity -> App Signing key certificate **TO** Firebase console.
2. I have also enabled **Android Device Verification** from Google Cloud Console as per [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification)
3. Also, I tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64952016/8874958) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65490555/8874958) questions, but didn't work.

Let me know if anyone has faced the same problem and found any solution. I am trying to find a solution to this problem from past couple of weeks. Sometimes I feel like Google's documentation is very poor!

Comment: After adding release SHA-1 and SHA256 key , download and replace the latest google-services.json file in your project.

Comment: @HimanshiThakur already done that and then re-uploaded over play store, still the same!

Comment: make sure PHONE AUTHENTICATION  is enabled and test on real device not on emulator .

Comment: share you app playstore link .

Comment: @KishanSolanki Please double-check and make sure to [select the correct project.](https://imgur.com/JtdgwHI)

Comment: @RumitPatel yes it's the same project selected that I am intended to do. No problem with it.

Comment: @KishanSolanki , Got any solution?

Comment: @RumitPatel thanks for the concerns, still no luck.

Comment: @KishanSolanki I am not sure but maybe it's possible. I faced this issue with my client's firebase account created for a country that is recently removed from [Firebase supported countries](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#phone-auth-countries). This may be the case.