# after updating flutter, Firebase.initializeApp() does not seem to work on my phone anymore

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio

I updated the flutter to the latest version today and after that the app is not loading on real device because something is going wrong with `Firebase.initializeApp()`.

It does seem to still work on the android emulator but not on real device.

This is the main.dart:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:major_capital_mobile_app/pages/login_page.dart';

void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // Create the initialization Future outside of `build`:
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire:
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child:
                Text('Not able to load app', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
          );
        }

        // Show app once complete
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Verification of phone',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData(
                primaryColor: Colors.black,
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                backgroundColor: Colors.black),
            home: const LoginPage(),
          );
        }

        // Else wait until initialization
        return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.lime,
                      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    )
                  ])
            ]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: major_capital_mobile_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  email_auth: ^1.0.0
  hexcolor: ^2.0.5
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  cloud_functions: ^3.0.4
  device_info: ^2.0.2
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.1
  get: ^4.3.8
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^19.3.48
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0
  chartjs: ^0.6.0
  fl_chart: ^0.40.2
  desktop_window: ^0.4.0
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid: ^19.3.53
  http: ^0.13.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  mockito: ^5.0.16
  rxdart: ^0.27.3
  pinput: ^1.2.2
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/data.json
    - assets/rounded.png
    - assets/mcm_white_logo.png
    - treeline2_Tekengebied.png
    - b_a_token.png
    - binance_coin.png
    - bitcoin.png
    - ethereum.png

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true


  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
  - family: CustomIcons
    fonts:
      - asset: lib/icons/fonts/CustomIcons.ttf

  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Like i said it seems to work on android emulator but once i try it on real device i get the message `not able to load app` on the screen so it seems it can load the app but its not successfully doing initiliazation of `Firebase.initializeApp().` to show the whole app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't what happend now but when i started the app again on my phone it worked. Yesterday i did a couple of things maybe that was the cause. I copy and pasted new sha1 and sha256 finger prints on Firebase Authentication. I found the solution on [Firebase phone authentication is not working on Android real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952016/firebase-phone-authentication-is-not-working-on-android-real-device)

Answer (score 1):

Do you give permission for internet in Manifest file of an android?

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: i have this inside ```android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml```

Comment: yes the permission is therre

Comment: ```<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mcma.major_capital_mobile_app">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```   The permission is there but its still not working

Answer (score 1):

Just add the **Firebase.initializeApp();** statment before running the app

```html
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const App());
}
```