# Random This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet..."

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, sms

I'm using Firebase Auth to authenticate my users using SMS in my Flutter app. I have set the fingerprints from Google Playstore in firebase and also I have this in my app/build.gradle

> implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'

The issue is that I'm having the following message in devices like Pixel 6 Pro, but users using Samsung device are able to login.

> This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither
> SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded. Please try again, or
> check the logcat for more details.

I have followed the suggested answers here:

- [Firebase phone authentication is not working on Android real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952016/firebase-phone-authentication-is-not-working-on-android-real-device/69601358#69601358)
- [This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither safetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490555/this-request-is-missing-a-valid-app-identifier-meaning-that-neither-safetynet-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem. The issue was that for some devices Android wasn't deleting the app info when deleting the flutter app, so somehow when installing a new version Android still had the old google-services file and thus giving this error.

So the final solution was to delete cache before installing the app.

Comment: deleting the app is not a solution you should add play integrity API to your app.

Comment: I just delete cache and  it works