# I did not receive sms verification code from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, sms

I am trying to write a code to send the verification code to SMS using Firebase Phone Auth .
but i got this error message :
E/FirebaseAuth(23757): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
error img [error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM18H.png)
my code

```
void phoneAuth() async {
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: "+966534341376",
  verificationCompleted: verificationComplete,
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
           print("the phone number not valid");
        } else {
           print(e);
        }
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) 
      async {
      
      },
     
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
      
   );
}
```

img of function
[function code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNJ9e.png)

here button calld function

```
MaterialButton(
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
   horizontal:
   smolewidt ? width * 0.12 : width * 0.28,vertical: 8),
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: n 
      BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
      color: sharedPref.getBool("mode") ?? "" == true
            ? redColor.primaryColor
            : redColor.primaryColor,
             onPressed: () async {
             phoneAuth();
             },
              child: Text("تسجيل جديد",
              style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 19,
              fontFamily: "NotoKufiArabic"))),
```

Comment: Did you check the rest of the error message, and search for that? https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+auth+missing+client+identifier This seems like a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952016/firebase-phone-authentication-is-not-working-on-android-real-device, but if that's not it, there are plenty of other mentions in the search results.